# Scanner and for loop

Tags: java, vector

I'm working on a piece of code and I'm trying to initialize a vector. However, the code somehow skipped through the first one and initialized a blank to my vector. Anyone knows why? Here's a snippet of my code:

```
public class Test{
private Vector<String> vecStr;

public void run(){
   vecStr = new Vector<String>();
   System.out.println("How many strings do you want for your string vector?");
   int numStr = keyboard.nextInt();
   System.out.println("Enter your string values.");
   for (int i=0;i<numStr;i++){
     System.out.println(i + "Input");
     vecStr.add(keyboard.nextLine());}
    }
  }
}
```

Let's say I input 4, somehow, the code gives me:

```
0
1
input:
2
input:
3
input:
```

It skipped the 0 one. Can someone please tell me why that happened? And if I were to display the Vector, it would give me : `[ , blah, blah, blah]`. How come there is a blank at the first element?

Comment: first get the input then add to the vector

Comment: this code cannot print such output, give us real output and real problem

Comment: Or at least try to run the example you've given us and show what it does (because the output you have included didn't come from your sample code).

Comment: Maybe add keyboard.nextLine(); once before the for loop

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention it but this is only a snippet of the real thing. The real code is very long and I wouldn't want to waste you guys' time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanner doesn't work on a line basis, but token basis. So, after your first `nextInt()` (for numStr) the scanner's cursor stays at the end of the input line (not start of next line). Therefore, first `nextLine()` execution right after that results in empty string. Subsequent calls to `nextLine()` then works correctly.

Comment: +1 but maybe an example would be clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use input stream readers:

```
    Vector<String> vecStr = new Vector<String>();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    System.out.println("How many strings do you want for your string vector?");
    int numStr = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
    System.out.println("Enter your string values:");
    for (int i=0;i<numStr;i++){
        System.out.println(i + " Input: ");
        vecStr.add(reader.readLine());
    }
    System.out.println("vector contains:");
    System.out.println(vecStr);
```